# Separating Interaction of Heat from Electricity?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, electric-fields, electrical-engineering

I have a rod where electricity of frequencies 1-360 Hz is passed through. It is affected by heat. I am evaluating the energy involved in such a process, contributed by electricity and heat.

The problem is that I have to work in very tight temperature range 30-38 C. 
There is always some heat affecting the total energy. The characteristics of material leads to its own characteristics: the rod is not completely parallel and can bend in the pathway. The power of the device is 4 V. The diameter of the rod is 1 mm.

I think the contribution of energy is centralised mostly by the electricity but distributed as Gaussian around the metal bar as heat according to the physical limitations set by the characteristics of the material.

How can you evaluate how much heat can be contributed in the total energy?
I have estimated by empirical results that it could be maximally 10-15%. 
I would like to separate heat from electricity in graphs made about the total energy. There should be some relationship here.

Comment: You replace the heating by the electric current by heating from an external heat source (e.g. an infrared heater) and you measure the temperature along the rod with thermocouples. To be very honest with you... I don't have the slightest clue what you are trying to do, though, as this doesn't sound like a particularly well characterized system. What is this used for?

Comment: Try a multi-physics simulation; this is what they are really good at.